# Select an element in contained DOM tree using d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Is it possible to select an element in contained DOM tree using d3.js?

For example, I have the following code:

**html**:

```
<div id="drawRegion">
  <div id="iWantToSelectThis">

  </div>
</div>
<div id="iWantToSelectThis">

</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

**js**:

```
const drawRegion= d3.select("#drawRegion");
```

Now in **js** I want to select the div with `id="iWantToSelectThis"` which is inside the div with `id="drawRegion"`. I hope to do so using the element I got here: `const drawRegion= d3.select("#drawRegion");`.

And if I will do just `d3.select("#drawRegion");` I will get two divs.

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique, use classes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it in one of two ways you can either create a more specific selector or select first `drawRegion` as you said and then select `iWantToSelectThis` from there.

**Option 1:**

```
let element = d3.select('#drawRegion>#iWantToSelectThis');
```

**Option 2:**

```
let drawRegion = d3.select('#drawRegion');

let element = drawRegion.select('#iWantToSelectThis');
```

Here is an example on how to do it: https://jsfiddle.net/5189rxfa/5/

Answer (score 2):

Id's must be unique, and d3.select will return only the first matching element from the DOM.

[From the doc :](http://d3indepth.com/selections/)

> d3.select selects the first matching element whilst d3.selectAll selects all matching elements. Each function takes a single argument which specifies the selector string.

So, add a class to your elements :

```
<div id="drawRegion">
  <div class="iWantToSelectThis" id="toSelect_1">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="iWantToSelectThis" id="toSelect_2"></div>
```

then if you want to select only the first element :

`d3.select('#toSelect_1');`

and if you want to select both :

`d3.selectAll('.iWantToSelectThis');`